# Why Force.com is not available when I right click on Package.xml file?

Tags: eclipse

When I right click on my `Package.xml` file in force IDE, I don't Force.com options. Please see the below image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Force.com menu appears on local files which have an equivalent file on the server. It allows you to deploy to/retrieve from the server and compare your local file with the server file.

Package.xml is only a local file so these options wouldn't make sense for it.